# As a software contractor, what should and shouldn't I bill for?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, contractors, contracting

I've been a software engineer for 4 years and I've recently picked up a side gig doing some contract work for another company.

I've had a few initial introductory and knowledge transfer meetings. I plan to bill for these. Is this appropriate? I'm not physically writing code, but this is required before I am able to, same as any other job.

How can I determine what are appropriate tasks to bill for and what are overhead tasks that are my cost of doing business?

Comment: Feedback along with the downvotes would be appreciated.

Comment: VTC - Primarily Opinion Based.  This is also a rather broad question too.

Comment: Hi Jim -- I didn't downvote but people are voting to close based on the question being too broad. There are a lot of considerations here, and many topics that could be discussed under what/what not to bill. It's a difficult question to write a succinct and objective answer for, which is what this site tries to do. Perhaps focus on one specific area that can be answered objectively. Also try https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

It depends on exactly what you're selling.  Most contractors sell their time so any time you work for the client is paid for.

Non delivery related time is generally not billed, such as sales or negotiations.

If you contract includes expenses, all reasonable expenses are billed as well.